# c++ frameworks yes or no

Tags: c++, frameworks

I am familiar with QT/gtk+ libs under linux. I've just roughly had a look at available c++ frameworks like Reason and Platinum. Does anyone have any experience working with any of them?  Are they any good, should I consider learning them? I am not a big fan of frameworks though.

Comment: subjective :) maybe if you give more specifics about your scenario, you can get more meaningful advice.

Comment: agreed, the question is subjective. The only objective part is that he knows Qt and gtk+.

Comment: I am mainly focused on small-weight client/server apps with or without gui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on a project that had to run on multiple platforms (Linux, Windows, Windows CE). We used [WxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) for the UI. The libraries and the tools weren't perfect. But it compiled and ran on all the platforms without any issues.

The platform is completely open source, so you have the benefits therein.

In the end, I was glad we used it as apposed to porting the UI layer multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Keep using Qt or gtk+. 
They're very good, and you already know them.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a fan of frameworks either, which is maybe why I haven't heard of those you mention. Having said that, check out [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/). Looks much better than Qt or gtk+ to me if you don't need GUI.

Answer (score 0):

[boost asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html): the framework for those who are not framework fans ;-).  (and this question still lacked a boost answer)

Answer (score 0):

I've started working a little bit with [Platinum C++.](http://www.pt-framework.org/index.html) The documentation is really lacking. That said, you can get some things off the ground relatively quickly. What I worry about is investing deeper into it and finding bugs without support or that it gets dropped as a project (or never really adopted) -- it is version 1.0.0.4

I sounds like you are practiced in keeping the general application mechanics independent and abstracted from one another. It may be worth writing your own small 'framework' and plugging in functionality from other projects with a small wrapper - particularly [boost](http://www.boost.org), as mentioned above. This is the direction I am going.